# PostgreSql remove difference between null and empty string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT location.id FROM location WHERE location.city = :city AND location.country = :country");
$stmt->execute(array(':city' => $cityVar, ':country' => $countryVar));
$locationID = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

I have faced a problem, because in database empty `city` column is sometimes null, sometimes empty string (I know it's wrong, but there is no way to change that). When my `$cityVar` variable is empty, I need to get all entries with needed `country`, but now I get only those where `city` column is empty string (I don't get those where `city` is null).

The only solution I come up with is to modify the query itself, for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT location.id FROM location WHERE location.country = :country ";
if ($cityVar) { 
   $sql .= "AND location.city = :city ";
}
```

but I was wondering if there is more legit ways to solve this problem. NOTE: there are more columns like `city` I need to search by.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `COALESCE(city, '')` - it will coerce `NULL` string to empty string `""`. If you have lots of cities and lots of queries to them, you can create an index on coalesced field to foster search.

```
"SELECT location.id FROM location WHERE COALESCE(location.city, '') = :city "
```

Comment: Should I use it as `WHERE COALESCE(location.city, "") = :city` in my query?

Comment: Better solution is to update the table set `null` fields to empty strings `''`. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you. I know it would be a better way, but unfortunately it is impossible in this case.

Comment: but by using a function (coalesce here) on the column, your query clause won't be able to use the index on location.city if it exists ..